# Finding equivalent API-supported data to the 2000 Census

Tags: data, api, united-states, census

I'm having some difficulty choosing Census datasets for a project that involve various SES measures at the block-group level. I'll be looking at things like median household income and percentage of people over 25 who have gone to college. These measures are available in the 2000 Census *and* I can use API to load them directly into R (the programming language I'll be using for the whole project).

What is the equivalent source for these measures that is **more recent than 2000 that work with API?**

The 2010 Census is formatted differently from the 2000 Census and doesn't seem to offer API functionality for non-demographic data in the SF2. I've considered the ACS 5-year datasets, but I'm worried it won't be as rigorous as the Decennial Census.

Here's the website that has API info for 10-year census.

http://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets/decennial-census-data.html

These are the variables for the ACS5. Helpful, but not ideal. 
http://api.census.gov/data/2010/acs5/variables.html

Comment: If this is open data then the place to ask may be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.